# R Importing excel file directly from web

Tags: r, excel, import, web

I need to import excel file directly from NYSE website. The spreadsheet url is https://quotespeed.morningstar.com/exportChartDataToExcel.jsp?tickers=AAPL&symbols=126.1.AAPL&st=1980-12-1&ed=2015-6-8&f=m&dty=1&types=1&ver=1.6.0&qs_wsid=E43474CC03753FE0E777D89877788ECB . Tried using gdata package and changing https to http but still doesnt work. Does anybody know solution to such issue?

EDIT: Has to be imported to R directly from website (project requirement)

Comment: An issue you are going to have is the link is a redirect and doesn't specify the actual *.xls file.  Do you have a link to the direct file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without information about why using the `gdata` package does not work for you I have to assume. Make sure you have `Perl` installed - you can download it at http://www.activestate.com/activeperl

This works for me:

```
library('gdata')

## URL broken into multiple lines for readability
url <- paste("https://quotespeed.morningstar.com/exportChartDataToExcel.",
    "jsp?tickers=AAPL&symbols=126.1.AAPL&st=1980-12-1&ed=2015-",
    "6-8&f=m&dty=1&types=1&ver=1.6.0&qs_wsid=E43474CC03753FE0E",
    "777D89877788ECB", sep = "")
url <- gsub("https", "http",url)
data <- read.xls(url, perl = "C:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe")
```

Without `perl = "path_to_perl.exe"` I got the error

```
Error in findPerl(verbose = verbose) : 
  perl executable not found. Use perl= argument to specify the correct path.
Error in file.exists(tfn) : invalid 'file' argument
```

Comment: If you put `perl.exe` on your path then you won't need the `perl=` argument.  Also note that if  for some reason you don't want to use gdata then using the `url` variable defined in the answer you could do `download.file(url, "MasterPrice.xls", mode = "wb")` to download the file and then read it using one of the many packages in R that can read Excel files such as the openxlsx, readxl or XLConnect packages.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for the note about adding `perl` to the `Path`! I never thought to do that. Also note the comment on the answer by @daattali where @nellevin states he cannot do the `download.file()` workaround although I would prefer that for later potential compatibility issues.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck What do you mean by adding `perl` to the `Path` to avoid `perl=` argument? Could you please show the example of code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RCurl` package to download the file and the `readxl` package by Hadley to read the excel file

Comment: Has to be imported to R directly from website (project requirement)

Comment: I don't understand what that would mean. Your link is a file, so the closest thing to "importing it directly to R" would mean to save the file and read it. You can't download a file into R. Maybe you want R to read the webpage, but in that case you don't want the file.

Comment: I think the notion is that the file should not be downloaded to a hard drive (even temporary folder) but rather read from the web directly into memory.

Comment: Exactly, file cannot be downloaded to a hard drive in any case. Reading from website might be more accurate term. Any idea lads?

Comment: In that case, instead of using the exported file, use the webpage that has the table in it, and use the `httr` package (also by Hadley) to read the table from the webpage directly