# Import of an excel file

Tags: r, excel, import

I try to download a file from NORDPOOL.COM into R, but somehow the xls format is changeing into a strange format

I have tried different file formats, but read.table is the only one that gives a meaningful table

```
 df <- read.table("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/regulating-prices_2019_hourly_dkk.xls")
```

I am looking for a dataframe that looks like the excel file....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Importing excel file directly from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30726180/r-importing-excel-file-directly-from-web)

Comment: Pay attention to the file format/extension of the data.  They're not all the same.

Comment: I don't think you can import that file directly. It has material above the header row that needs to be formatted/removed? And probably easier to import with `read.xlsx` from `xlsx`.

Comment: I can see there is an issue there, but i am blank tbh... i see an XLS file and I can open it in excel. I try to import it as an excel file, things goes bad... the thing i get looks like html... but i try HTML formats  to import and nothing comes out of it..  Can u give a hint how you would import the spread sheet?

Comment: IMHO, I would first just download the file to the working directory, open the file in Excel, delete the top three rows (and if necessary, prefix things like "NO1" from the third row to the respective columns in the row below it containing the column names), insert a column description for the date column (1st column), and then import into R as follows `importdata <- read.xlsx(file = "regulating-prices_2019_hourly_dkk.xls", header = TRUE, sheetName = "Sheet1")`. Note: you'll need the `xlsx` package and its dependencies installed for this.

Comment: Even better, I'd convert the file to the CSV format, and then just use `read.table` (one can avoid having to deal with `xlsx` entirely that way). Whether all of this is feasible depends on how many files you'd have to deal with. I think a lot of this manual work *could* be automated with an `awk` script or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

`rvest` can be helpful as,

```
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/globalassets/marketdata-excel-files/regulating-prices_2019_hourly_dkk.xls")

out <- page %>%  html_node("table")   %>%    html_table()
out <- out[-c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,23,24,25,26)]
colnames(out) <- c("Date","Hour","DK1_Up","DK1_Down","DK2_Up","DK2_Down")

head(out)

         Date    Hour DK1_Up DK1_Down DK2_Up DK2_Down
5  01-01-2019 00 - 01 211,45   211,45 211,45   211,45
6  01-01-2019 01 - 02  75,19    75,19  75,19    75,19
7  01-01-2019 02 - 03 -30,46   -30,46 -30,46   -30,46
8  01-01-2019 03 - 04 -73,99   -73,99 -73,99   -73,99
9  01-01-2019 04 - 05 -55,33   -55,33 -55,33   -55,33
10 01-01-2019 05 - 06 -93,71   -93,71 -93,71   -93,71
```

However, it is an **irregular** data, to arrange it, you have to have a look at the inside of the `.xls` file. That was what I did actually. So I think,  after downloading the file and making the necessary arrangements,  reading the file in `R` still a good option comparing to `rvest`.